# Set the request Authorization header in SFSafariViewController

Tags: token, jwt, request-headers, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have application that have username and password, so that user logs to the app. 
Some (less important) functionality is still as web page.

But to be user friendly, it is annoying for user to login again after already logging in.

I am looking at the SFSafariViewController and it looks promising, but I am trying to set the Authorization header when calling the URL. I already know the user token, but it needs to be set as Authorization headers.

So the flow it would be:

```
User log in inside App -> get token -> set this token as Authorization header -> call my web app url
```

Is this possible with this controller?

Comment: @Jeff, the site you are browsing is controlled by you or not? If yes then you should just be able to do this using cookies? SFSafariViewController will share cookies with Safari. Also see if this helps by anyway https://github.com/MrCaiWH/HHDemo/blob/825a378d03c4f89e208e128a71d4bf5060747e87/HHDemo/HHDemo/Classes/Modules/Encoded/Controller/HHEncodedVC.m

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, (@Jeff didn't' post the question :D ). Yes the site is under my control, and yes, I could do it with cookies. But, as I remember you can't set your own cookie with code in SFSafariViewController. I know that it could share cookie store with Safari, but I don't want to login with Safari first, but inside my application...

Comment: You can navigate to a url in SFSafariViewController which is sets the cookies itself? And since your control the site, creating such a url should still be possible?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you suggest that I create new endpoint on web site, where you put username and password inside url and if correct set the cookies. On button than I open firstly this endpoint and then the original one when the cookie will be set? How would I know when I need to call original site? Do you have any example of calling one site one after another...

Comment: So you will redirect to first url itself, which should check if cookie is set, if not it redirects to login, where user logins and after successful login, you redirect back to the first url which now works. Next time when you come Safari will have your cookies stored, so login page will not be shown till the cookies is valid. And in case you need to set the token in headers you will use `axios` middleware to automatically add auth headers to request. So eventually it can all be handled with web itself. Any information you need to communicate from your app can go to special url as query params

Comment: Please read my question again : "But to be user friendly, it is annoying for user to login again after already logging in." First login is inside application and not web page. So user logs inside my application, and then some of them would like to open web page. It is impractical to log in again inside web page,... this is the whole point of the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169618/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-marko-zadravec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed this what you should do

When you login from the app you receive a token. Next you should create an extra endpoint for `login`, say `loginWithToken`. The format of the same could be something like

```
https://example.com/loginWithToken?token=xyz&returnURL=def
```

From your app you will navigate this URL and then it would do the same thing a `login` page would have done. Store this token wither in `cookies` or `localStorage`. Once done the page should redirect to the `returnURL`

This way the app will without any re-login required from the `SFSafariViewController`

Comment: Is there any possible security issues with the token passed on the URL? I guess not but it's good to get more opinions.

Comment: I don't think this should have a security issue. I have seen this approach in few places

Comment: This is absolutely a security issue. The user may tap the Share button before the page loads, and unwittingly share the URL (with their token included) on social media.

Comment: @jason, you can use JWT to timeout the token. And that time can be as short as you want

Comment: Correct, and that's a mitigation of someone logging in as another user. However, the JWT may have other PII encoded such as a name or email. You must be very careful with this approach.

Comment: @Jason is right. Don't do that.